# Subir datos desde base de datos local a servidor

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqldb

He creado el siguiente código para enviar información desde mi base de datos local a la base de datos online, el problema es que necesito subir a la base de datos online toda las columnas name e ID que cumplan el "WHERE pass = 'user';" pero como lo he hecho solo se me pasan a la base de datos online el primer registro. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

```
<?php
//LOCAL

$servername1 = "localhost";
$database1 = "livesystem";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
// Crear conexion
$conn1 = mysqli_connect($servername1, $username1, $password1, $database1);
// Verificar conexion
if (!$conn1) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Conexion correcta con el servidor local. - ";


 $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn1,"SELECT * FROM result") or die ("Error: $sql1");
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_all($sql1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$nombre = $mostrar['name'];
$ID = $mostrar['ID'];



//SERVER

$servername = "s";
$database = "ds";
$username = "u";
$password = "p";
// Crear conexion
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
//Verificar conexion
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Conexion correcta con el servidor online. - ";

foreach($mostrar as $campo=>$r)
    mysqli_query($conn,"
        INSERT INTO comp (nombre, ID)
            VALUES ('".$r['nombre']."', '".$r['ID']."')
    ");

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: He pensado en usar mysql dump pero no se bien como usarla

Comment: Dump te permitirá hacer un volcado puntual, pero no pasar los datos de una base de datos a otra conforme se van registrando en la de origen. Intenta describir el contexto para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Te explico mas detalladamente, tengo un programa para la gestión de resultados de competiciones deportivas, este programa trabaja con una base de datos local, pero yo necesito enviar datos de las tablas de la base de datos local a una base de datos online que tengo en mi servidor para poder publicar los resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, vamos a la fuente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Debes empezar por crear las conexiones con ambas bases de datos. Después, con el método query, continuar lanzando instrucciones SQL a ambos servidores, de forma que pases toda la información de la base de datos local a la de tu servidor web.

El problema que tienes, ahora que has modificado la pregunta, es que sólo traes un registro con la función `mysqli_fetch_array` y sólo haces un `INSERT`.

Para resolverlo tienes que utilizar la función `mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` y recorrer el array resultante con un `foreach` y realizar un `INSERT` de varios registros o varios `INSERT`.

Donde tienes:

```
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
```

Utiliza:

```
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_all($sql1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

En `$mostrar` tendrás un array asociativo con todos los registros de la consulta que has lanzando.

Para recorrer ese array, e insertar cada nuevo registro, puedes hacer algo así:

```
foreach($mostrar as $campo=>$r)
    mysqli_query($conn,"
        INSERT INTO comp (nombre, ID)
            VALUES ('".$r['nombre']."', '".$r['ID']."')
    ");
```

Inténtalo y, si tienes dificultades, modifica la pregunta y te indicamos cómo hacerlo.

Comment: He pensado en hacer algo así, primero tengo un archivo de conexión,y después el archivo principal, como podría hacer para que alfo así funcionara <?Php
$servername1 = "ipserver";
$database1 = "registro";
$username1 = "usuario";
$password1 = "contraseña";

$servername2 = "localhost";
$database2 = "ianseo";
$username2 = "root";
$password2 = "";
?>

Comment: El archivo principal sería el siguiente: <?php
 include 'conexion.php';
//La tabla de localhost de la que quiero sacar los datos es "result" y la columna de la quiero sacar los datos es  "name"

$conlocal = mysqli_connect($servername2, $username2, $password2, $database2);

$sql = SELECT name, FROM result;

//La tabla del servidor en la que quiero meter los datos es "comp" y la columna en la que quiero introducir los datos es "nombre"

$conserver = mysqli_connect($servername1, $username1, $password1, $database1);
INSERT INTO comp (nombre) VALUES ('$sql');

?>

Comment: Hola Javier, vamos a hacer las cosas bien pues, de lo contrario, nos van a poner aún más votos negativos: modifica tu pregunta incluyendo todos tus comentarios y yo concretaré mi respuesta para que te resulte útil. De esta forma recibirás incluso más respuestas que la mía y dejaremos un problema resuelto para quien se lo vuelva a encontrar en el futuro.

Comment: Buenas, ya he cambiado la pregunta, espero haber sido más claro ahora. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Genial, ya vas aprendiendo a preguntar, buen trabajo. Cuanto más sencilla plantees la pregunta, más respuestas obtendrás. En cuanto hagas el bucle que te indico, ya lo tendrás.

Comment: No termino de entender como utilizar esa función, las sustituyo por mysqli_fetch_array y que tendría que hacer después para q el valor de la variable $nombre e $ID sea la columna completa?

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta. Si te queda cualquier duda, modifica de nuevo la pregunta concretando tu duda manteniendo todo lo anterior, o plantea una nueva pregunta desde cero, como prefieras

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ya funciona